# Compare two List and return a new list with only the columns that have different values

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to compare List1 and List2 [List2 is the edited List1], then produce a list with only the updated columns and updated value

**List 1**

```
var x = (from a in table1 where id == 1 select a).firstordefault();
```

produces below

```
ID | Val1 | Val2 | Val3 | Val4 | Val5
-------------------------
1  | A    | B    | C    | D    | E
```

after item with ID = 1 is updated

**List 2**

```
ID | Val1 | Val2 | Val3 | Val4 | Val5
-------------------------
1  | A    | C    | C    | F    | E
```

Then compare **List 1** and **List 2** to produce **Output List**

**Output List**

```
ID | Val2 | Val4 |
-------------------
1  |  C   | F    |
```

Comment: And your question is ? Don't it just need comparing 2 list ? Or you have some restrictions ?

Comment: @Kosmas no restrictions at all. I just need to produce the third one using the first 2 lists.

Comment: What  are `Val1/2/3`? are they properties of the object? Are there more or is it only these 3? Does `ID` stay the same?

Comment: @GiladGreen Val1/2/3 should be the column name. ID stays the same, column count can be more than 3.

Comment: My main purpose is to track the updated columns of a record and return them as list but with only the updated columns

Comment: @DheoAgbuya Can you show us declaration of your List? Are `Id`, `Val1`, `Val2`, `Val3` properties?

Comment: @bommelding i've updated the example. Kindly have a look at it.

Comment: @bommelding i am comparing 2 lists with only 1 row. First element sequence

Comment: @bommelding please see the updated post

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Difference
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Val1 {get;set;}
    public string Val2 {get;set;}
    public string Val3 {get;set;}
    public string Val4 {get;set;}
    public string Val5 {get;set;}
}

var result = new List<Difference>();
var props = typeof(Difference).GetProperties();
foreach(var origin in source)
{
    var against = updated.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == origin.Id);
    if(against != null)
    {
        var diff = new Difference{ Id = origin.Id };
        var add = false;
        foreach(var prop in props)
        {
            var againstVal = prop.GetValue(against);
            if(prop.GetValue(origin) != againstVal)
            {
                prop.SetValue(diff, againstVal)
                add = true;
            }
        }
        if(add)
            result.Add(diff);
    }
}

foreach(var res in result)
{
    foreach(var prop in props)
    {
        var val = prop.Value;
        if(val != null)
            Console.Write($"{prop.Name}:{prop.Value} ")
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
//output:
//Id:1 Val2:C Val4:F
//Id:2 Val2:C Val3:F Val13:S
//...
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how would i implement this on a linq select query?

Comment: First select `source` list, then `updated` list and then apply my algorithm.

Comment: `source` is the old, `result` is after i updated the `source`, am i correct?

Comment: `source` - `List1`, `updated` - `List2`, `result` - `Output List`

Comment: I am getting the 'No overload for method 'GetValue' takes 1 argument'

Comment: It is strange look at [this method description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Reflection_PropertyInfo_GetValue_System_Object_) or try `prop.GetValue(against, null)`

Answer (score 0):

You made it difficult for yourself that you want only the information about the changed property values. This makes that every row in your result has a different number of values.

Besides you forgot to tell us whether the value in the `Id` column is the index of the item in the list, or whether every list element has a property `Id`.

Furthermore: is the type of your list already known at compile time or is it only known at run time. In other words, is it a `List<TSource>`, or is it more like a `System.Data.DataTable`?

Another problem: Is Id unique? And if List 2 has an element with Id = 5, but List 1 doesn't have a Row with this Id, do you want it in the result as an added value? If List 1 has an Id that is not present in List 2, is it a removed value?

> By the way, I hate it if people react with: "oh sorry, I
>   forgot to mention that Id in fact is the index of item in the list, oh, and I
>   also forgot to mention that my two lists have equal length, you can't
>   add or remove elements from the list". For !@#% sake! Get proper
>   specifications before you ask a question!

### `List<TSource>`

This solution detects errors at compile time. The compiler won't compile if you try to put an item in your list without an `Id`. You get errors if you accidently try to compare a DateTime with a string, etc. The problem however is that you have to know in advance what items are in your Lists.

```
IEnumerable<TSource> ListA = ...
IEnumerable<TSource> ListB = ...
```

To make sure that your `TSource` has a notion of `Id` I will not make a function where the input is a `List<TSource>`, but a List>`, where the`int`is the Id. This can be the index of the`TSource` in your list, or one of the properties.

The conversion from `List<TSource>`, to List>` is simple:

```
// The index is the Id
static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, TSource> ToIndexedPair<TSource>(
       this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    return source.Select( (source, index) => 
         new KeyValuePair<int, TSource>(index, source));
}

// The index is one of the properties:
static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, TSource> ToIndexedPair<TSource>(
       this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
       Func<TSource, int> IdSelector)
{
    return source.Select(source => new KeyValuePair<int, TSource>
          (IdSelector(source), source));
}
```

Now that we've identified the Id, we can give the signature of the function

```
IEnumerable<...> ExtractDifferences<TSource>(
    IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, TSource> listA,
    IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, TSource> listB)
{
    ...
}
```

As output, you want a sequence of objects, containing an `Id` and a sequence of `DiffInfo`, where every `DiffInfo` contains information about the changed value: some indication about the property that has been changed, and the changed value. For fun I'll also add the original value.

The problem is: In your result, you want a sequence of changed properties with the changed values. These values can be `Datetime`, as well as `int` or `string`, or any other class. So in the return sequence, All I know about the properties in your list is that they are `objects` and that they have values. You can't do much with `objects`, unless you know some more about them, hence I also provide the `PropertyInfo`

```
class DiffPropertyInfo<TSource>
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public TSource OriginalValue {get; set;}
    public TSource AlternativeValues {get; set;}
    public PropertyInfo PropertyInfo {get; set;}

    public object OriginalPropertyValue
    {
        get {return this.PropertyInfo.GetValue(this.OriginalValue);}
    }

    public object AlternativePropertyValue
    {
        get { return this.PropertyInfo.GetValue(this.AlternativeValue); }
    }

    public bool IsChanged()
    {
        object originalPropertyValue = this.OriginalPropertyValue;
        object alternativePropertyValue = this.AlternativePropertyValue;

        return Object.Equals(originalPropertyValue, alternativePropertyValue);
    }
}
```

Note, by defining the class this way, I only have to store some pointers and the `Id`. The fairly expensive GetPropertyValue is not used until you really ask whether it the value has been changed.

By the way: use `Object.Equals`, not `X == Y`, because if the fetched objects are value types, then we want the proper overridden version of `Equals`. Also, if you have a class that overrides Object.Equals, you want that equality, not the default `Object.Equals`.

Extract the different properties between two TSource objects:

```
IEnumerable<DiffPropertyInfo> ExtractProperties(int Id, TSource original, TSource alternative)
{
     // examine only readable properties that can be changed:
     IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> propertyInfos = typeof(TSource)
        .GetProperties()
        .Where(property => property.CanRead && property.CanWrite);

     // the following can be done as one LINQ statement
     // for readability I'll use yield return
     foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in propertyInfos
     {
         yield return new DiffPropertyInfo()
         {
              Id = Id,
              OriginalValue = original,
              AlternativeValue = alternative,
              PropertyInfo = propertyInfo, 
         };
     }
}
```

For every element in your input sequences we need to store the result of the differences:

```
class PropertyComparisonCollection<TSource>
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public TSource OriginalValue {get; set;}
    public TSource AlternativeValues {get; set;}

    // returns a sequence of changed properties:
    public IEnumerable<DiffPropertyInfo> GetChangedProperties()
    {
         // Use the function ExtractProperties defined above
         return Extractproperties(this.OriginalValue, this.AlternativeValue)
             .Where(extractedpropery => extractedProperty.IsChanged());
    }

}
```

Here you see the same method: don't calculate the differences until someone asks for it.

So now we can go back to the original function that will do what you want:

```
IEnumerable<...> ExtractDifferences<TSource>(
    IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, TSource> listA,
    IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, TSource> listB)
{
    // The Id is in the Key of the KeyValuePair
    // inner join on same Id and get Id / OriginalValue / AlternativeValue
    // then Create PropertyComparisonCollection per Id / OriginalValue / AlternativeValue
    // Finally per Id return the properties that are changed

    return listA.Join(listB,       // join ListA and ListB
       listA => listA.Key,         // from every ListA take the Key (which is Id)
       listB => listB.Key,         // from every ListB take the Key
       (listA, listB) => new PropertyComparisonCollection() // when they match
       {                                                    // make one new object
           Id = listA.Key,
           OriginalValue = listA.Value,
           AlternativeValue = listB.Value,
       })
       // Keep only the Ids that have at least one changed value
       .Where(collectionElement => collectionElement.GetChangedProperties().Any());
}
```

The result is a sequence of `DiffPropertyInfo`. Every element in the sequence contains the `Id`, the `OriginalValue` and the `AlternativeValue`. You can ask every element for the properties that are changed.

If you really want only the Id and the changed property values (as what? as string? as object? ) use GetChangedProperties:

```
.Select(collectionElement => new
{
    Id = collectionElement.Id,
    ChangedValues = collectionElement.GetChangedProperties()
        .Select(changedProperty => changedProperty.AlternativeValue,
});
```

But with that you'll lose a lot of information. I'd go for the original returned collection where you can easily find out the changed values.

By the way, did you notice that until know I didn't enumerate? Your sequences are not accessed yet. Not one comparison has been made, no PropertyInfos are enumerated yet, etc. As soon as you ask for the first element, the PropertyInfos are enumerated, and the first values are fetched.

Note: some people wouldn't like this separation in various classes. If you want, you can put this all together into one big LINQ statement. I'm not sure if that would improve readability, reusability, maintainability, and testability.